# JPA join same child table with a differen key

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have situation that the same table is linked two different keys
all names either it manager's name or name of the employee stored in "employee_table" reason is manager is also an employee

```
manager_link_table
id
manager_id

employee_table
id
name
```

Now I want two child objects as below
I am trying to create JPA Entity with OneToOne as

```
@Entity
@Table(name="manager_link_table")
class ManagerLinkTable {

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn( name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
private EmployeeTable employee;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn( name="id", referencedColumnName="manager_id")
private EmployeeTable manager;

}


@Entity
@Table(name="employee_table")
class EmployeeTable {
private String id;
private String name;
}
```

I am writing JPA query as

```
SELECT m FROM ManagerLinkTable m
```

I want m.employee.name and m.manager.name to be different
But I am getting the same, it seems the referencedColumnName is ignored while joining the table
Does anyone faced this issue ?

Comment: The object oriented world and the relational world are different. You shouldn't model "Tables" in your code, but Entities. "Link-tables" are often just modeled as relationships in JPA, not Entities.
But I have a hard time understanding what you are trying to do. Maybe you can post a short example with your tables, relevant columns only.

Wouldn't you just want to have an "Employee" and a "Manager" Entity?

Comment: the table design is not my control, the manager's name is the employee table and employee's name is also in the employee's table, the employ can or cannot have a manger

Comment: I'm not talking about the table design, but about the JPA Entity design (the Java code).